# Magento 2 maintenance mode doesn't work

Tags: magento-2.1, maintenance

I have website maintenance mode and it allow open just homepage. It show errors when open example categories, products and admin dashboard, Error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.
```

I run ssh command php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip="my ip"

So how i can use fully website when is maintenance mode enabled? This is important so i can make website fixes. I want that customers cannot see/use website when there is maintenance.

Comment: Do you have full page cache enabled?

Comment: Yes, Varnish cache

Comment: The issue is documented here. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8975

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that when you are using Varnish as full page cache, all requests that are reaching Apache are made by Varnish, therefor the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will always contain the varnish IP (127.0.0.1).

One quick solution would be to edit your `index.php` and read a the client IP from a different key in the `$_SERVER` global and set it on `REMOTE_ADDR`

Like for example:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

} else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) { 
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
```

You can at least try and see if this works.

Comment: Varnish will then serve the cached resources to unauthorized clients. #justSaying

Comment: @vitoriodachef can you provide a use case scenario where this will happen?

Comment: Sure. You are an authorized client to access a specific resource say homepage. if the homepage is cacheable, Varnish will cache it. It will then serve it to the next client that tries to access the homepage. Varnish knows nothing of authorization and is between the client and Magento. This is a known issue (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8975).

Comment: I see your point, and yes, that makes sense. However, I consider it's a separate issue than the one presented by the OP

Comment: I agree. Just sharing info.

Answer (score 0):

Please switch to production mode and try again. You can run following command to switch to production mode.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Because when developer mode is enabled, you will get such message.

Comment: Now it show website for me  Service Temporarily Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. and my ip is allow use website, you see my command top.

Comment: From where you found your IP ?

Comment: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: Ok. Please open var/.maintenance.ip file and check IP there.

Comment: There is right my ip.

Comment: Okay. Did you try flush or clear cache ?

Comment: Yes, I tried also php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento setup:di:compile, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy, php bin/magento indexer:reindex, php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I can open just homepage. Others pages show error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

To permit access to specific IP address:

> php bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips 123.45.67.89

Comment: OR php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=123.45.67.89

Comment: Doesn't work. Production mode: Service Temporarily Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: From where you found your IP ?

Comment: Same error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Create `phpinfo()` on root of your server and hit it.

You will find there one field `REMOTE_ADDR` copy ip from it.

And enable maintenance mode using that ip.

`php bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips remote_addr_ip`

Remember you'll again have to repeat same if you see maintenance mode again. As `remote_addr` field changed.

Answer (score 0):

For Enable & disable of maintenance mode in magento 2, Just follow some steps:

Use the magento maintenance CLI command to enable or disable Magento maintenance mode.

Command usage:

magento maintenance:enable [--ip= ... --ip=] | [ip=none]

magento maintenance:disable [--ip= ... --ip=] |[ip=none]

magento maintenance:status